# How to debug rails when doing an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So, usually, rails errors and gives me a nice error page to read from. There is also a console to debug in.

But, when doing an ajax call like this:

```
  $('.the-button').mousedown(function(ev) {
      var returned_stand_id = 1
        $.ajax({url: "/stands/create", type: "POST", contentType: "application/json", dataType: "json",
                data: '{"the_name": "' + returned_stand_id +  '"}',
            success: function(data){
              returned_the_id = data.the.id;
              window.location = '/s/' + returned_the_id;
            }
        });

    });
```

I get a chrome error on the console of:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

My question is not what is the problem in this instance.

My question is how do I display a helpful rails error messages when testing/debuging ajax calls.

EDIT 1:
I added:

```
 ...
          window.location = '/s/' + returned_the_id;
        }
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
          console.log("jqXHR = "+JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
          console.log("textStatus = "+JSON.stringify(textStatus));
          console.log("errorThrown = "+JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
        }
 ...
```

But, this just caused the JS to fail to load with an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

This error is specifically on:  `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){`

Comment: Testing/debugging? So you need this to fix the problem? In this case, just consult your rails log. It has the stacktrace and the request parameters, which should be enough for most cases.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, Do you know if there is a way to, if the rails server fails, forward the user to the page that the ajax call is receiving (the error page)?

Comment: If Rails is erroring with a 500 error, then there's no page sent in the response: just the error.  If you want to send the user to a different url in the case of an 500 error then that url will need to be in your javascript already so you can redirect to it in your error block for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sergio says, look in your rails log for details of the error.  However, to answer your question, you can output more info about the error in your javascript code by adding an `error` block to the ajax call options.

```
$('.the-button').mousedown(function(ev) {
    var returned_stand_id = 1
      $.ajax({
          url: "/stands/create", type: "POST", contentType: "application/json", dataType: "json",
          data: '{"the_name": "' + returned_stand_id +  '"}',
          success: function(data){
            returned_the_id = data.the.id;
            window.location = '/s/' + returned_the_id;
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            console.log("jqXHR = "+JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
            console.log("textStatus = "+JSON.stringify(textStatus));
            console.log("errorThrown = "+JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
          }              
      });

  });
```

It might show the rails stack trace.

Comment: Sadly, adding this JS,  in the way described in the edit I added, just causes an error upon loading.

Comment: It will need a comma between it and the success block: I'll edit to show the whole thing.